# Special power supply - High-voltage diodes in series

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, high-voltage

I am working on a homemade non-transferred arc plasma torch, a device that generates and sustains an electric arc, that is blown in particular conditions.

The power supply is composed of two subsystems: a “low”-voltage power supply (up to 1000 V) running at high power and current-controlled (close to 100 kW at maximum power), and a high-voltage power supply (up to 30 kV) running at low power (up to 50 W).

The high-voltage power supply ignites an arc with a quick discharge (a few tens of µs), and the low-voltage power supply has to react as quickly as possible to sustain the arc once it is ignited.

Both power supplies are connected in parallel, and currently, the high-voltage is going towards the low-voltage power supply as its resistance seems to be lower than the one of the plasma system. To avoid this problem, I want to put in diodes to avoid the current going towards the low-voltage power supply.

For that, I need a diode that can sustain >100 A and >25 kV, which is really expensive to do with only one diode, so I want to use several [MDQ 150A 1600V](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1391461/GoldElectric/MDQ150A1600V/1) diodes in series, 20 diodes for safety, to increase the reverse voltage capacity of the circuit.

While reverse-biased, the blocking voltage of each diode is different as the diodes need to carry the same leakage current. I read online that this problem can be solved by connecting resistances across every diode. Voltage would be shared equally; hence the leakage current would differ.

However, I’m having trouble calculating the value of the resistors.

I used several sources, for example [this calculator](https://ohmslawcalculator.com/led-resistor-calculator). I often come across the value of 3 MΩ per resistor, which is doable, but seems a bit high.

Does anyone have an idea on how I should proceed?

Here is a basic schematic of what I’m trying to achieve:

[image: Schematic of the setup]

Comment: The datasheet of the diode you linked does not give any leakage current rating, which makes it unsuitable for your application. You need a diode whose manufacturer actually tells you the leakage current.

Comment: Why not an HF start as most welders use?

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, indeed this info is missing.
@TimWilliams I'm using a laser HV power supply that works pretty well. The low-voltage power supply works well as well, all alone. It's when I combine both that problems happens.
I could move the electrodes closer to generate the arc with the low-voltage one only, but that would require significant design change in the setup !

Comment: And 4kW of diodes isn't a "significant design change"..?

Comment: It is, I underestimated the complexity of the diode solution. I will still try to figure out a way to make it work without modifying the mechanical setup too much, as months of numerical simulations were involved!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is pretty difficult to achieve.

Let's take the Vishay VS-VSKE320-20PBF as an example, which is a 2kV, 320A diode that (unlike the one you linked) actually gives a rating for its maximum reverse leakage current: 50mA.

If you apply 30kV to a string of such diodes, the diodes may well dissipate 30kV * 50mA = **1500 W** due to their leakage current alone, thereby hopelessly overloading your 30kV power supply. In order for this to work, the leakage current of the diodes has to be around 1mA or less instead.

It seems like silicon carbide Schottky diodes might just work, but they will be pretty expensive.

The GD60MPS17H from GeneSiC is a 1.7kV 122A diode with a typical leakage current of 41µA at 175°C and maximum reverse voltage. This means that you could pass around 200µA through the balancing resistors to keep their reverse voltage drops matched, for a total leakage of roughly 0.25mA. With 1.5kV across each diode, you'd need 20 of them in series, and a 7.5 MOhm resistor across each of them. This will still dissipate 7.5 Watts due to its leakage current, but your 30kV power supply will be able to handle it.

Make sure to cool these diodes appropriately as they will each dissipate almost 300 Watts if you actually pass 100A through them (6kW in total). The case temperature of each diode has to stay below 100°C.

The only downside is that that's $1k in diodes alone, and probably just as much in heatsinks.

It might be more realistic to put two of these diodes in parallel each, for a total of 40 diodes ($2k), which would lower the total power dissipation to around 4kW at 100A due to the significantly lower forward drop at lower currents. (Make sure to add current sharing resistors if you go that route.)

Another suitable diode would be the STTH3010D, which is a 1kV 30A type that costs about $2 each. You'll have to put 4 of them in parallel, and 40 in series, for a total of 160 diodes. Additionally, you'll need a 10 Milliohm balancing resistor in series with each diode. The power dissipation in each diode will be 40 Watts (25A per diode), and each resistor will dissipate another 6.25W. In total, that's 7.4kW dissipation for all 160 diodes and resistors combined.

The cost of the diodes will likely be negligible compared to the cost of the cooling solution for them, though. You might very well save money by using the more expensive silicon carbide diodes. To put things into perspective: To cool those diodes dissipating 7.4kW, you will need something like a car radiator, or maybe even multiple, plus an expensive water-cooling setup with very expensive coldplates to mount the diodes on.

Alternatively, you could use a different ignition voltage source, such as a transformer in series with the 1kV 100A supply's output that can temporarily superimpose a large AC ignition voltage onto the 1kV DC. The transformer will likely have to be pretty insane too, though, since it must handle both the 100A current (thick secondary winding), as well as the 30kV ignition voltage (extremely good isolation). Its power dissipation will be much lower than that of the diodes, and it will likely also be cheaper. It will, however, be more difficult to build.

Comment: If I apply 30kV to a string of such diodes, how could they dissipate 30kV * 50mA if the total power of the HV supply is 50W ? I might be missing something, I'm definitely not from an electronic background !

Thank you very much for your tips and interesting insights, I will try to find other diodes that fit in my budget (ideally under $200 in total for the diodes).

Comment: They *would* dissipate 1500W if the PSU could deliver that amount of power. Since it can't, the PSU will just give up and its output voltage will collapse. In other words: It'll be overloaded.

Comment: I see, you made some very good points, thanks.
I still have a vocabulary question, does the Fig. 5 of [this datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1403063/Rectron/HVP20/1/) represent the leakage current ?
Is "Instantaneous reverse current" a synonym of leakage current ?

Comment: $200 is absolutely unrealistic for this kind of project. You might get the diodes for $300, but then you need a cooling solution for them that likely costs five figures. And yes, figure 5 in the datasheet you linked does give the diode's leakage current. You need 100 (better 150) of these diodes in parallel to handle your 100A, so you'll have to multiply this current by 100 (or 150). 20µA \* 150 = 3mA -> overload (90W). The diode you linked won't work. You'd ideally stay below 0.5mA because the balancing resistors also draw some additional current.

Comment: Also, even if you were able to use the HVP20 (maybe you buy a better 30kV PSU), you will still have a huge problem: You'll need 150 of these diodes in parallel to handle the current, and two sets of diodes in series to handle the voltage. That's 300 diodes in total. Each diode dissipates about 20W, so you'll have to cool 6kW again. That necessitates a very large industrial chiller unit, which is a five-figure deal. You're basically trying to keep a large oven at 50°C by cooling it with heatsinks and fans.

Comment: Okay, it seems way more complex than I expected, thank you for your explanation. The only goal of the diodes was to avoid getting the current flowing in the low-voltage psu, but flow towards the electrodes instead. Do you have any other solution in mind that could work?

Comment: Like I've mentioned at the end of the answer, you can put the secondary of heavy-duty high voltage transformer in series with the 1kV/100A output to superimpose a starting voltage pulse. The transformer's secondary has to be able to handle the 100A continuously.

Comment: It would be interesting to follow this path indeed, I will do some research on that.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I managed to find a diode reference that seems suited for this application. I still have to solve the problem of heat dissipation when the low-voltage psu kicks in. Do you think that using a relay (or a switch) to "dodge" the diodes, once the arc is ignited, is a good idea? That could be activated through a timed signal, this way the diodes' heating would still be at high power lever, but for a short period of time, resulting in little energy to dissipate.

Comment: That might work, but a 30kV 100A relay will be extremely expensive and hard to find. If you use a "normal" low-voltage relay, it'll just arc over. One relay that will likely work is the Gigavac G52WF. It'll cost you a couple thousand dollars, though.

Comment: If the relay is placed "before" the diodes on the circuit, on the low-voltage psu side, then it should not be exposed to 30kV as the diodes would be there to block the high-voltage discharge, and I would only need to find a 1200V 150A relay. What is your opinion on that?
Any idea where I could look to find such a device?

Comment: Think about that idea again: If the relay is in series with the diodes ("before" them), the diodes are always in circuit and the full 100A flows through them. That makes the relay pointless as the diodes will always dissipate at least 4kW anyway. You have to put the relay in parallel to the diodes so you can short ("bypass") them, which means that the relay is exposed both to 30kV (when open) and to 100A (when closed).

Comment: Indeed, what I want to achieve is to power the red OR the blue part of the circuit of [this schematic](https://postimg.cc/XXgWMkMF), with a switching device that could be programmed. 
This way, the relay should never be exposed to 30kV as the diodes would block the HV discharge. To secure the design, I would still go for a HV relay, but probably <30kV.

Comment: EDIT: You are right, the relay would need to be insulated for 30kV indeed, as the current could flow through the red wire and arc inside of the relay.

The challenge is to find such a relay with very fast close & release speeds.

Comment: I was about to write that exact comment, but you were faster :P - Indeed, there is no way around using a relay rated for *both* 30kV and 100A at the same time, and this kind of relay costs a LOT. Such relays are usually used in the medium voltage sections of the power grid. You have to choose between spending a couple thousand dollars on cooling your diodes, or spending a couple thousand dollars on a ridiculous relay. The diode solution is not really viable - use a transformer instead to generate a high-voltage high-frequency start pulse.

Comment: As you said earlier, building such a transformer is a challenge, and I do not think I am autonomous enough yet for this task, so I'm trying to make it work with diodes.